# How to compile (and link) a COBOL program in an IBMi from the command line?

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I have a COBOL program:

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.        
 PROGRAM-ID. HELLO1.             
 AUTHOR. MYSELF.                 
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.             
*    SHOW BEGINS                 
     DISPLAY 'HELLO WORLD RUN'.
     STOP RUN.
```

If I compile it with the option 14 of the STRPDM it runs.
But if I try this from the command line(F10):

```
CRTPGM PGM(HIGINIO1/HELLO2) MODULE(*PGM) ENTMOD(*FIRST) BNDSRVPGM(*NONE) BNDDIR(*NONE) ACTGRP(*ENTMOD) TGTRLS(*CURRENT)
```

It fails: Program HELLO2 not created.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the ILE languages, you first have to compile the module. Then create the program from the module.

use `CRTCBLMOD` command to create the module:

```
CRTCBLMOD MODULE(yourlib/TEST0007B) SRCFILE(QCBLLESRC)
          OPTION(*SOURCE) DBGVIEW(*SOURCE)
```

run `CRTPGM` command to create executable program from the module:

```
CRTPGM PGM(TEST0007B) MODULE(*PGM)
```

Here is a cobol sql example ( did not get too far because I do not fully understand how to perform a loop in cobol ). Use the`CRTSQLCBLI` command to create the module. Then `CRTPGM` to create the program.

```
CRTSQLCBLI OBJ(TEST0008B) SRCFILE(QCBLLESRC)
          SRCMBR(TEST0008B) OBJTYPE(*MODULE) REPLACE(*YES)            
crtpgm  test0008b   

     IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                 
       PROGRAM-ID. TEST0008B.                                 
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                  
       CONFIGURATION SECTION.                                 
         SOURCE-COMPUTER. IBM-ISERIES.                        
         OBJECT-COMPUTER. IBM-ISERIES.                        
       DATA DIVISION.                                         
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                               
       01  A     PIC X(80) VALUE " ".                         
       01  B     PIC S9(8) VALUE 10.                          
       01  C     PIC S9(8) VALUE 5.                           
         01  SR_FILLER.                                       
             05  sr_srcdta               PIC x(100) VALUE " ".
           EXEC SQL                                           
                INCLUDE SQLCA                                 
           END-EXEC.                                          
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                    
       MAINLINE.                                              
           MOVE B TO C.                                       
           exec sql                                           
                declare c1 cursor for                         
                select  a.srcdta                              
                from    qrpglesrc a                           
           end-exec.                   
           exec sql                    
                open    c1             
           end-exec.                   
                                       
           EXEC SQL                    
                fetch  c1              
                into   :sr_srcdta      
           END-EXEC.                   
                                       
           if      sqlcode not = 0     
           display 'end of input file' 
           else                        
           DISPLAY sr_srcdta           
           END-IF.                     
                                       
           EXEC SQL                    
                close  c1              
           END-EXEC.                   
                                       
           EXEC SQL                    
                SELECT a.srcdta        
                  INTO :sr_srcdta      
                  FROM qrpglesrc a                     
                  fetch first row only 
           END-EXEC.                   
           DISPLAY sr_srcdta.          
           STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Thank you @RockBoro. It works! Only a small thing: The srcfile is where the member pertains SRCFILE(QCBLLELESRC) because is a Cobol program in this case. Then to run: CALL yourlib/yourpgm

Comment: I have a running disagreement with every programmer I have ever worked with. I prefer to place all my code in a single source file. Regardless of SRCTYPE.  I use QRPGLESRC for everything.

Comment: Did you tried VS CODE with the extension Code for IBM i? Is where the compile/link option in COBOL I had to add/modify in settings.

Comment: should be pointed out that option 14 from PDM uses CRTBNDCBL, which will do both steps automatically.

Comment: Yes, according with @Charles using CRTBNDCBL (yourlib/yourmember) SRCFILE(QCBLLESRC) OPTION(*SOURCE) DBGVIEW(*SOURCE) its works "all in one"

Comment: @RockBoro Good on you! NP, myself I create a sourcefile for each project. Old PC habits! –